# React Native - Dimensions.set() is not working?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I am new to `react native` and learning about handling the screen dimension for Android platform. I imported the `Dimensions` module and did everything right but when i call the `Dimensions.set()` method, nothing is happening. Here is the script:

```
<Button title='Set Dimension' onPress={() => {
    Dimensions.set({
        "width": 300,
        "height": 300,
        "scale": 1,
        "fontScale": 2
    });
}}/>
```

Can anyone tell whats wrong with my script and how to use this method? A little example will be more appreciated. Thanks !!!

Answer (score 2):

if you will refer the facebooks's doc for dimensions [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/dimensions#set) `set()` method can only be called from native code and needs to be exposed with didUpdateDimensions event.

Comment: So you mean i have to set the `didUpdateDimension` event on the `java` side and then i have to call the `Dimensions.set()` from react native?

Comment: Yes I think you have to do this.